# Jenkins: where is the login.keychain file in /Users/*name*/Library/Keychains folder?

Tags: ios, macos, jenkins, continuous-integration, macos-sierra

I am trying to packaging an iOS ipa with Jenkins. So I get Keychains and Provisioning Profiles Management plugin and try to upload keychain which it needs.
My Mac operating system is sierra(10.12.2), I enter the folder at /Users/admin/Library/Keychains. But there is only a file called login.keychain-db and it's doesn't work when I have uploaded this file on Jenkins. The error says that uploaded file "login.keychain-db" is no keychain or provisioning profile file.
So how can I solve it or where can I find login.keychain file?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I have same issue can some body solve it.

Comment: @Ashok I still can't find a way to solve this problem. Because of Xcode Plugin in Jenkins, I must find this file. But now, I use python/shell to handle `xcodebuild` command to archive ipa.

Comment: can you explain me further please?

Comment: @Ashok I dropped Keychains and Provisioning Profiles Plugin. Using `xcodebuild` in python or shell to build/sign IPA to instead. The documentation by Apple: [xcodebuild](https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/xcodebuild.1.html)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can simply unlock your keychain through shell.
In your Jenkins project configuration, add an 'execute a script shell' step :

```
security unlock-keychain -p PASSWORD ${HOME}/Library/Keychains/login.keychain

security set-keychain-settings -t 3600 -l ${HOME}/Library/Keychains/login.keychain
```

Note. The 'set-keychain-settings' leaves the keychain unlocked for a while (3600s), so your build process (*xcodebuild* in your case) still have access to the keychain when it's signing the IPA.

Note 2. The keychain extension changed with Sierra, it's now .keychain-db indeed. Using directly the security command won't affect you.

Comment: Thank you anyway. I dropped Keychains and Provisioning Profiles Plugin eventually. I compared the same file path with my workmates and my old Mac. The result is some Macs get `login.keychain` file in that folder (same os, Sierra) but some don't.